# Differential geometry and differential topology graduate program options

Tags: soft-question

I am a physics undergraduate student from a University in Mexico, I am about to graduate, right about the middle of my undergraduate studies I realized I was more into math than into physics, I did some self study in several areas (Set Theory, General and Algebraic Topology, Number Theory and much more on Topology). This is almost my last semester and I am taking a first course on differential geometry, which I found fascinating, as I self studied some math, I got very good at it. And since my course was for physicists, my professor notice I did remarkably good and offer me to get into a graduate program (Master + PhD) on Differential Geometry in CIMAT (This is Math research centre here in Mexico) which I found exciting, and finally I decided to pursue a career in this field.

I have read some books on Differential Geometry and Differential Topology (I find Diff. Topology quite more elegant) nevertheless I am interested in both fields, as they are intimately related, but before making a decision on whether to get into CIMAT I want to know what other options are good for taking a graduate program in, I really think I will be able to get into good programs, but I really need the scholarship as well, I was wondering if someone could point out some options I might have.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you make an appointment with Dr. Luis Hernandez and ask for his suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is your question? CIMAT offers the PhD in Differential Geometry. La UNAM would be also be a very good option.